# Difficulty finding multinomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

Find the coefficient of $x^{18}$ in the expansion of $(1+x^{3}+x^{5}+x^{7})^{100}$

I got the following answer:

$\binom{100}{96,2,1,1} + \binom{100}{94,6,0,0}$

But the answer given is:

$\binom{100}{6} + 97 \times 98 \times \binom{100}{2} + 97 \times \binom{100}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\begin{array}{}
18&=7+5+3*2&\equiv\binom{100}2\binom{98}1\binom{97}1&=\binom{100}2\times98\times97
\\&=5*3+3&\equiv\binom{100}3\binom{97}1&=\binom{100}3\times97
\\&=3*6&\equiv\binom{100}6&=\binom{100}6
\end{array}$$

Comment: oh! Thank you! I realized I missed out the 5*3+3 = 18. Is there any way to check the number of possible ways to calculate the coefficient so that I can avoid this mistake?

Comment: @Faizal start greed with 7 then 5 then 3 which are less than 18, eg. 7*2+? not possible, 7*1+? possible: 7*1+5*2+? not possible, 7*1+5*1+? possible:7*1+5*1+3*2 and so on.